# Not able to configure aem dipatcher with httpd in mac using brew. Getting error Symbol not found: _apr_stat$INODE64\n

Tags: apache2, aem, dispatcher

Installed httpd using brew install httpd and tried to add load module for dispatcher module in httpd.conf

When I do configtest I get below :

apachectl configtest
httpd: Syntax error on line 182 of /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf: Cannot load lib/httpd/modules/mod_dispatcher.so into server: dlopen(/usr/local/opt/httpd/lib/httpd/modules/mod_dispatcher.so, 10): Symbol not found: _apr_stat$INODE64\n  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/httpd/lib/httpd/modules/mod_dispatcher.so\n  Expected in: flat namespace\n in /usr/local/opt/httpd/lib/httpd/modules/mod_dispatcher.so

dispatcher downloaded from https://www.adobeaemcloud.com/content/companies/public/adobe/dispatcher/dispatcher.html

Comment: you might have downloaded a dispatcher that is not compatible with your httpd installation.

Comment: Dispatcher compatibility -> apache 2.2 =  dispatcher-apache2.2 & apache 2.4 =  dispatcher-apache2.4